# Problem with CSS Hover-Tooltips in combination with overflow:scroll/auto (and position absolute)

Tags: html, css, scroll, hover, tooltip

I'm having trouble with my css hover tooltips in combination with containers that have overflow-y:auto (or scroll).

Either the hoverBox is contained inside that container and not popping out of it as intended, causing the tooltip to barely be visible.

Or if I "fix" this problem by changing position:relative on the container (commented in the code/link below), I have a new problem where the hoverBox position is lower than it should be when I scroll down inside the container, until it completely disappears below the bottom end of the window when you scroll down far enough on long lists.

https://jsfiddle.net/tcdueLvo/

Since the page is far from a static website, explicitly setting the hoverBox positions (or updating them whenever something moves) is not an option.

```html
<style>
    .TTTrigger + div {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #a38d6d;
        z-index: 99999;
        min-width: 300px;
    }

    .TTTrigger:hover + div {
        display: inline-table;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 150px; /*position: relative;*/ width: 150px;">
        <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hover</div><br>
        <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hover</div><br>
        <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hover</div><br>
        <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hover</div><br>
        <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hover</div><br>
        <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hover</div><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to solve by css. I recommend change your web design or control tooltip position by jQuery.

```js
$(".TTTrigger").hover(function() {
  const div = $(this).next("div");
  const top = $(this).offset().top + div.height();
  div.css("top", `${top}px`)
  div.addClass("d-inline-table");
}, function() {
  $(this).next("div").removeClass("d-inline-table");
})
```

```css
.TTTrigger+div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #a38d6d;
  z-index: 99999;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.d-inline-table {
  display: inline-table!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 150px; /*position: relative;*/ width: 150px;">
    <p class="TTTrigger">text</p>
    <div>hover</div><br>
    <p class="TTTrigger">text</p>
    <div>hover</div><br>
    <p class="TTTrigger">text</p>
    <div>hover</div><br>
    <p class="TTTrigger">text</p>
    <div>hover</div><br>
    <p class="TTTrigger">text</p>
    <div>hover</div><br>
    <p class="TTTrigger">text</p>
    <div>hover</div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to do it! But are you sure about the "+ div.height()"? This caused some larger toolTips to still be too far below the actual element. Removing this addition fixed everything for me! Thanks!

Comment: @user13028150 Put your arbitrary formula there and place the elements in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following to create the tooltip is wrong. You should wrap your `<p>` element and `<div>` (hover) element in a parent `<div>` whose position should be set to **relative**. The hover `<div>` should be set to absolute and should be positioned relative to the outer `<div>`.

I have used your code and modified it to follow the approach and it's working.

```
<style>
    .TTTrigger + div {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #a38d6d;
        z-index: 99999;
        min-width: 300px;
    }

    .container {
       width: 400px;
       height:400px;
    }
    .tooltip-container
    {
      position:relative;
      margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    .tooltip-container div
    {
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:30px;
    }
    .tooltip-container:hover div
    {
      display:block;
    }
</style>
  <div class="container">
       <div class="tooltip-container">
         <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hoverBox toolTip text that explains some stuff</div>
       </div>
        <div class="tooltip-container">
         <p class="TTTrigger">text</p><div>hoverBox toolTip text that explains some stuff</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your solution code does not have the overflow enabled though. If I re-set the overflow of the container to auto and reduce its size a bit, I still have the same problem as initially, where the hoverBox is stuck inside the container and not readable for smaller containers and/or larger toolTips.